# Location of connection string to WSS_Content DB

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I've got an error during long-running operation on sharepoint site.

Database ConnectionString: 'Data Source=...... Connect Timeout=15'    ConnectionState: Closed ConnectionTimeout: 15

Where can I find connection string to sharepoint site for changing Connect Timeout time?

Answer (score 1):

you're not going to like this answer, but you really shouldn't be mucking around in the config database changing things.  This really isn't a supported option and you are more likely to cause yourself present and future pain than you are to fix it.

A better solution would be to address your long running transaction to see if you can making it better somehow or to understand why it failed.

Answer (score 0):

SharePoint stores its connection string information in a configuration
database. This is where it stores all information regarding web application /
site collections and their related databases.

To find out where the appropriate databases are (server) and what they are
called, you will want to utilize the Central Administration interface, and
look under:  Applications Management --> Content Databases